# What does distinct mean in terms of an array?

Tags: terminology, arrays

I've tried searching this up, but from my what I think it is. It means there are no duplicate elements (ie. all elements are unique elements)?

Comment: Can you include the context in which you encountered this term?

Comment: I was watching  video where they mentioned that an array was both sorted and distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the ordinary English-language use of the word "distinct". The objects in some collection are described as "distinct" if each is different from the others. So an array with distinct elements is one where no two elements are the same.

> **distinct**, adjective
>
> 1. Recognizably different in nature from something else of a similar type:
>
>    - ‘the patterns of spoken language are distinct from those of writing’
>    - ‘there are two distinct types of sickle cell disease’
>
> — [OxfordDictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/distinct)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.. 
An array is distinct if it contains unique elements i.e. no duplicates

Comment: It's not the array that is distinct, but the elements. That is, you can say "an array with distinct elements" but not "a distinct array".